# How to move from user defined function directly to a chart?

Tags: python, return-value, pie-chart

I'm trying to build a module that will count all the color words in a text and then display them on a pie chart. I already have the counting and the chart coded separately, but I can't figure out how to connect them.

Right now I have:

```
def colorperc(text):
    y0 = text.count("red")...text.count("rust")
    y1 = ... 
    return {y0...y10}

colorperc(mobydick.txt)

...
fracs y0, y1...
```

How do I take these return values and plug them into the piechart fracs? I just keep getting an error: NameError: name 'y0' is not defined

Comment: Can you tell us more about what coding language you are using?

Comment: Oh sorry. It's in python.

Comment: The error is probably caused because `y0` is not defined within the scope that you are accessing it. `y0` is a local variable and is only a valid identifier within the scope of the `colorperc` function.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `text.count` is unlikely to do what you want.

```
>>> "Red wired tired".count("red")
2
```

You will probably want to read through the text line by line, lowercase and split each line, and update a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).  Then as Matt said, you will need to assign the value returned by your function rather than trying to access local variables.

Since your comment says you're using nltk, perhaps something like this (untested). We'll assume you're happy having the whole text in memory, since that matches your problem description.

```
from collections import Counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import nltk

def countcolors(text)
  tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
  tokens = map(lamda x: x.lower(), tokens)
  ctr = Counter(tokens)
  colorlist = ("red", "rust", "blue", "green")
  colorcounts = dict((color,ctr[color]) for clr in colorlist)
  return colorcounts

#we'll call the text in memory `mytext`

colors, counts = countcolors(mytext).items()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.pie(counts,labels=colors)
plt.show()
```

Note that we simply use assignment (with `=`) to get the value returned by the function.

Comment: I'm using the nltk to actually read the texts (I'm having to do about fifteen, so I want this module to be reusable), but what I don't know how to do is assign the value returned by the function.